# Remove item form array but keep event listener

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-listener

I have an array of items to which I have appended the same event listener, and I need to drop a specific item from the array, but I'd like to keep the event listener on it.

Of course I could add it separately, but I was wondering if there was an easy way.

[Here is a pen to show that.](https://codepen.io/Zemp/pen/mdBaabb)
The function that is supposed to remove the focus from the buttons after some time does not execute on the third button.

Here is the JavaScript for more clearness:

```
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".button")];
let dropButton;

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        setTimeout(() => { buttons[i].blur(); }, 500);
    });
    
    if(buttons[i].classList.contains("drop")) {
        dropButton = buttons.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Well the third button is no longer inside the `buttons` array, have you considered using `this` inside the event function to achieve the blur?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event listener does keep connected, but when pressing the "dropped" button, the handler will blur the wrong button. This is because your handler accesses the `buttons[i]` by an index that is not valid anymore.

These are three other solutions that may be possible for your handler:

```
  // assigning the button to a closure scoped constant
  const b = buttons[i];
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    setTimeout(() => {b.blur();}, 500);
  })
```

or

```
// the "this" context in the handler is the button
buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
  setTimeout(() => { this.blur();}, 500);
})
```

or

```
// the handler get and event whose "target" key is the button
buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
   setTimeout(() => {event.target.blur();}, 500);
})
```

Comment: Clear and simple, thanks a lot!